# How to customise select tags in a form in Symfony

Tags: forms, class, symfony, select, symfony6

I try to display a form with Symfony. In the form, I am asking for birthdate ans I would like to give a class to select which is in a form widget. At the moment, I just could give class to form widget itself. How do I can do it ?

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Incris-toi !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<main class="form container">

    <header></header>

    {{form_start(userform)}}

        <div class="page" id="page2">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{form_widget(userform.gender, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Es-tu un homme ou une femme ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}})}}
                {{form_label(userform.gender, 'Es-tu un homme ou une femme ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}})}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{form_widget(userform.firstname, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Quel est ton prénom ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}})}}
                {{form_label(userform.firstname, 'Quel est ton prénom ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}})}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                {{form_widget(userform.lastname, {'attr' : {'placeholder' : 'Quel est ton prénom ?', 'class' : 'form-control'}})}}
                {{form_label(userform.lastname, 'Quel est ton nom de famille ?', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'label'}})}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                <p>Quelle est ta date de naissance ?</p>
                {{form_widget(userform.birthdate, {'select' : {'class' : 'form-select'}})}}
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary mt-4 d-flex mx-auto">Suivant</button>
        </div>

    {{form_end(userform)}}

</main>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the html code that I can see on the browser :
[image: HTML code]

Comment: If you're trying to add bootstrap classes to your form elements, you can let Symfony do that for you by using the bootstrap form theme: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap5.html

Comment: Hi Marleen. I am already using Bootstrap. I placed it in my base.html.twig and I already have Bootstrap style on the other inputs. I just wish to find a way to put form-select in select class.

Comment: If you add the `form_themes: ['bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig']` line to your `twig.yaml` file, as in the 2nd code block example on the page I linked above, Symfony will automatically add bootstrap classes to all of your form elements. This should also add the right bootstrap classes to your select.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried but I have this error message : There is no extension able to load the configuration for "form_themes".

Comment: I had a look on this documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html. I just don't find the file config/packages/twig.php.

Comment: There's just a typo in your code `{{form_widget(userform.birthdate, {'select' : {'class': 'form-select'}}) }}`  it's not `select` but `attr`. But if you are already using the form theme, it should add them automatically

Comment: Do you have a `config/packages/twig.yaml` file? Could you post it's contents (edit the opening post)?

Comment: Yes. I just tried but I have this error message : There is no extension able to load the configuration for "form_themes".

Comment: You probably have an error with the indentation in your twig.yaml file. Make sure the `form_themes` line is properly indented, it should start with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I get the gist that others believe you are having difficulty setting the `select`'s attribute, whereas I understood you had an issue with `option` elements. At least that is what the question's title says. Please correct me if I am wrong :)

I haven't done this myself, but according to the docs, it should be possible.

If you look at the file: `vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`, you should see a block called `choice_widget_options`. This is the point where all `<option>`s and `<outgroup>`s are built.

For `<option>` tags, there is the code:

```
<option value="{{ choice.value }}"{% if choice.attr %}{% with { attr: choice.attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}{% if not render_preferred_choices|default(false) and choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice_translation_domain is same as(false) ? choice.label : choice.label|trans(choice.labelTranslationParameters, choice_translation_domain) }}</option>
```

Please note the part:

```
{% if choice.attr %}{% with { attr: choice.attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}
```

Finally, looking at the `Choice` component, you can see there is a way to set the `choice_attr`. I would *assume* that you can lean on this and set it for each individual item. This can be done either via hardcoded values or via Closure:

```
'choice_attr' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
    // adds a class like attending_yes, attending_no, etc
    return ['class' => 'attending_'.strtolower($key)];
},
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Hello Jovan. I try to add a class in class tag indeed. Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the title.

Comment: I am visiting the file. I think my problem has smth to do with {%- block date_widget -%}.

Comment: Well, if it were a `ChoiceType` I'd have suggested that as well for the elements, but the issue seems to be with the `DateType` when using `'widget' => 'choice'`. Short of a custom `form_theme`, I don't know another way to do that. But I might be wrong, I'd be interested in knowing that this actually works and inherits the option.